# How can I make my nav bar display properly when being zoomed in mobile device?

Tags: html, ios, css

I have made a nav bar by using a `nav` element, which contains a large `div` element. The `div` element then contains three smaller `div` elements.

I made the `nav` element `position: fixed; min-width: 100vw`.

The large `div` element has `position: relative; height: 10vw`.

All three small divs has `display: inline-block` and some `width` and `margins`, and the third one has `position: absolute; right: 0`.

The settings work perfectly well when I test them in the latest Chrome version for OSX, but when I view the page through my iPad (both Safari and Chrome for iOS) and zoom in using two fingers, a part of the nav bar was out of the screen.

I tried not to use the `min-width: 100vw` style, but only got the result that the third `div` drops out from the nav bar into a new line when being zoomed in.

Can any tell me how to fix the problem to make bar display properly when being zoomed?

[Here is the nav bar I work on.](http://blog.rainland.tk/)

Comment: Please share the actual code in the question, rather than portions of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the code: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />` in your `head` section. This will disable zooming entirely though...

Also try defining **both** the height and width of the nav.

Comment: You're right. I learned this meta tag before and had added it to my html, but somehow thought it doesn't work in chrome for iOS during earlier tests, while it does work. As for the safari, I just learned Apple has disabled user-scalable=no in iOS10 safari, which explains the situation.